# Ruby on rails transposing rows into columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am coding with ruby on rails. Current I have a table with `client_name`, `item_name,` and `amount` of that item. It looks like this:

[image: table 1]

I want to convert the table to with `client_name` and each `item_name` as column followed with the count. It should looks like this:

[image: Table 2]

I use mysql, so Pivot seems not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Pivot Table Gem](https://github.com/edjames/pivot_table)

Add the following to your gem file

```
gem 'pivot_table'
```

Then from your console

```
bundle install
```

After that create a module

```
# lib/PivotTable
module PivotTable
  def grid(data, options = {})
    grid = PivotTable::Grid.new do |g|
      g.source_data = data
      g.column_name = options[:column_name]
      g.row_name = options[:row_name]
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can get the pivoted table data from your own controller(Assumin the tables is orders)

```
include PivotTable

def my_method
  orders = Order.all
  grid = grid(orders, { :row_name => :client_name, :column_name => :item_name })
  # do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your have an array named `@clients` and each client in that list has – at least – the following attributes: `client_name`, `item_name`, and `amount`.

Than I would group that list by `client_name` and each sub list of items client by `item_name` then it is easy to generate a nested array that only includes the required data

```
# When the list of item names is fixed
item_names = %w[alpha beta charlie]

# When the list of item names is dynamic
item_names = @clients.map(&:item_name).unique.sort

grouped_list = @clients
  .group_by(&:client_name)
  .map { |name, clients| [name, clients.group_by(&:item_name)] }
  .map { |(name, items)| [name, *item_names.map { |item| items[item]&.amount }]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to solve the problem, But thanks everyone. I will try your methods as well.

sql1="SELECT client_name,"

```
for item_name in @items_name
  sql1<<" SUM(CASE WHEN item_name="
  sql1<<"'#{item_name}'"
  sql1<<" THEN amount END) AS "
  sql1<<"'#{item_name}'"
  sql1<<","
end
sql1=sql1[0...-1]
sql1<<" FROM sourcetable GROUP BY client_name ORDER BY client_name"
```